# How to append data?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

Here's my code in `code.gs`:

```js
function appendData(name1,phone2,drop1,email) {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("page");
  ws.appendRow([name1,phone2,drop1,email]);
}

function getuser(){
  return Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
}
```

Here's my code in `userform.html`:

```html
var name1 = nameBox.value;
              var phone2 = phoneBox.value;
              var drop1 = dropBox.value;
              var email = google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function(err){
        console.error("error occured", e);
    })
    .withSuccessHandler(function(res){
        alert(res);
    })
    .getuser();

google.script.run.appendData(name1,phone2,drop1,email);
```

I know my code will pop out a message showing my email address...but what I want to do is to append the email address from this: `google.script.run.appendData(name1,phone2,drop1,email);`

It does append `name1`,`phone2`, and `drop1`, but not `email`

How do I do that?

Comment: tried this but still not working:


var email = function test() {
              var test = google.script.run.getuser();
              return test;
             
              }
              
 

              google.script.run.appendData(name1,phone2,drop1,email);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved by:

```
 function appendData(name1,phone2,drop1) {
 var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("page");
 var user1 = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
 ws.appendRow([name1,phone2,drop1,user1]);

}
```